# Get multiple strings from a single JTextField

Tags: java, string, swing, jtextfield

I have  this text field inside a dialog

```
        dialog.setSize(350,350);

        dialog.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,
                new JTextField(text));
```

My goal is when user adds  multiple strings inside that text field, to extract the text and split it into strings, and then be able to search in a DB for each string like this:

```
var res =  request_handler.search(
"SELECT Name, ingredients  FROM " +
    "food WHERE FIND_IN_SET('"+containerObj+"',ingredients)");
```

I'm thinking for something like this:

```
 String foodSearch = ActionField.getText();
 int index = 0;
//create a contaner for the strings
ArrayList<String> container = new ArrayList<>();
container.add("");
//loop until end of string
while(index <= foodSearch.length()){
  //if we aren't at new string
    if(foodSearch.charAt(index) != ','){
      //get the char
       char temp =  foodSearch.charAt(index);
        //then append that char to the String in the container
    }
   else{
        container.add("");
    }
    ++index;
}
```

Basically will use the comma sign as a separation between the strings, looping thru the whole object. But is there a better way of approaching and solving this problem?

Comment: yup, use StringTokenizer or if you want to work with arrays, .split() works too, then delimit either with your choice delimiter ","

Comment: Use the Force Luke! Force = `java.util.StringTokenizer`. Also you can use the `split` method of String. Something like `String[] tokens = textField.getText().split(",");`

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: For something like this I think it's just better to utilize a JTextArea in your dialog instead of a JTextField. I feel it would less error prone and easier to edit if a User can enter each item (String) on a separate line within the text component (which can not be done in a JTextField). Split the text: `String[] lines = jTextArea1.getText().split("\n");`. All text lines contained within the JTextArea will now be in the `lines` String Array....do as you like with them when iterating through the array and  ignoring blank elements if any are encountered.

Comment: Thank you very much all! I guess using the force instead of creating  my own is what people actually mean by "don't reinvent the wheel "
@DevilsHnd - I actually end up doing it that way and in fact catched some corner cases as you mentioned

Comment: Uhhhh... the Dark Side.